# VBA - to clear table based on number of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clear Table "A" - based on number of rows present in Table "A"

For example
if there is less than 2 rows present in Table "A" then clear all contents in Table "A"

```
with sheets("DOC").ListObjects("A")
if A.Rows.Count > 2 Then
A.databodyrange.ClearContents
ENDif
ENDwith
```

I know for sure this wrong because it keeps giving me an error.
Wondering how to fix this or if there is a better way.

any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`ListObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject) has a [`ListRows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.listrows) property:

```
With Sheets("DOC").ListObjects("A")
   If .ListRows.Count < 2 Then
       .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
   End If
End With
```

Also, if you want to check for fewer than 2 rows, then use `<`, not `>`.

However, if a table has 0 `.ListRows`, then its `.DataBodyRange` is `Nothing`. So, maybe better to check if it has only 1 row.

```
With Sheets("DOC").ListObjects("A")
   If .ListRows.Count = 1 Then
       .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
   End If
End With
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your response, for some reasons it wouldn't clear the content of table "A" when there is less than 2 rows present.

Comment: If you want to check if fewer than 2 rows, then change the `>` to `<`.

Comment: You really should be checking if it only has one row to be honest. If it has zero rows, you can't clear its `.DataBodyRange`.

Comment: i am aware that if it has 0 rows it will never clear but my table data always has either 1 row or more than 1 row . so basically i just want remove the table if there is no more than 2 rows of data.


Thanks again!